# check combination from a collection exists in a table

Tags: php, mysql

One of my db table has columns `COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3` which hold ids of users. This group of 3 should be unique. Mean `stu1, stu2, stu3` record exists in above columns, it cannot have `stu2, stu1, stu3` again. But it can have `stu1, stu2, stu4`

and and I have an array of students i.e `[stu1, stu2, stu3, ....... stuN]`

N could go upto 5000

What is the most efficient approach to find a combination from the array, which is not a duplicate.

I am using mysql and php (latest versions)

Comment: Note that this kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design; any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, question whether your design is optimal

Answer (score 0):

As @Strawberry noted in their comment, the design of the table (and the necessity of this query) seems suspicious. But assuming that it has to be this way, there's a couple of ways to go about this. A nice and clean trick would be to leverage the ordering capabilities of `JSON_EXTRACT()`:

```
SELECT t2.ids, COUNT(1) occurrences
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.col1,
    t.col2,
    t.col3,
    JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_OBJECT(col1, col1, col2, col2, col3, col3), '$.*') ids
    FROM test t
  ) t2
GROUP BY t2.ids
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4fKbzCtxkMPu5MDAd6jdR9/0)'s a working example. The idea here is that we create a JSON object containing the three ids (as both keys and values), and when we extract it again it will be ordered by key. Then we can just group by and count.